# Better Algorithm? Better Array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, random

**This is my code:**

```
/* Name: Steven Royster
 * Date: Jan. 15, 2015
 * Rock, Paper, Scissors Program
 * This program simulates a game of rock, paper, scissors with the user until someone has one a        total of five times.
 */
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RPS {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Let's play rock, paper, scissors! First to five wins!");

    String[] choice = { "zero" , "rock" , "paper" , "scissors" };
    Random rander = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userScore = 0, compScore = 0,
        userChoice,    compChoice;


    while (compScore < 5 && userScore < 5)
    {
        compChoice = rander.nextInt(3) + 1;

        System.out.println("\nEnter: 1 for ROCK | 2 for PAPER | 3 for SCISSORS.");
        userChoice = input.nextInt();

        if (compChoice == userChoice)                                     // tie
        {
            System.out.println("I chose " + choice[compChoice] + " too, so we tied!");
        }
        else if ( ( compChoice == 1 && userChoice == 3 )                 //computer wins
               || ( compChoice == 2 && userChoice == 1 ) 
               || ( compChoice == 3 && userChoice == 2) )
        {
            System.out.println("I win! I chose " + choice[compChoice] + ". " +
                               choice[compChoice] + " beats " + choice[userChoice] + "." );
            compScore += 1;
        }

        else                                                             //human wins
        {
            System.out.println("You win! I chose " + choice[compChoice] + ". " +
                               choice[userChoice] + " beats " + choice[compChoice] + ".");
            userScore += 1;
        }


    }//end while

    if (userScore == 5)
    {
        System.out.println("\nCongrats! You're the winner! You got " 
                           + userScore + " points. I only got " + compScore + " points." );
    }
 }//end main
}//end class
```

**Is there a better algorithm I can implement rather than using the three separate conditions within my else-if statement? Also, instead of having the 'zero' string in my array, how could I check through my array using only numbers 1, 2, and 3?**

Comment: This question is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Luc M Okay, thank you. Was not aware of that option. I'm a new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
String[] choice = { "rock" , "paper" , "scissors" };
```

Then instead of `choice[userChoice]` you can do `choice[userChoice - 1]`.

You don't need to write

```
if ( ( compChoice == 1 && userChoice == 3 )              
           || ( compChoice == 2 && userChoice == 1 ) 
           || ( compChoice == 3 && userChoice == 2) )
```

because it is the same as

```
if (compChoice == 1 + (userChoice % 3))
```